# Message queue oriented design in e.g. ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: message-queue, activemq-artemis, system-design

I have problems on designing message queue oriented design on a clustered fault tolerant system.

There are three sites A B C.

B is clustered as B1 B2 B3.

C is clustered as C1 C2 C3.

A message X (1000-5000 Xs per second actually) is sent to B cluster from Site A.

B converts it to Y and sends it to C.

C converts it to Z and sends it to B.

If the connection between A and B fails A sends X to C. Now C converts it to Z and sends Z to B.

If all connections of A fail then A stores Xs locally.

I have looked at the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis (formerly JBoss HornetQ), but I cannot exactly figure out whether it fulfils my above scenario.